# Python to php server Get Data

Tags: php, python, json, raspberry-pi

Ok I'm a little confused here I need to send data to a php server and receive back a response from it example: a raspberry pi sends a unit id and the server returns json file.

I have tried this .py code

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost/updateContent.php'
payload = {"device":"gabriel","data_type":"data","zone":1,"sample":4,"count":0,"time_stamp":"00:00"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

but obviously this post the data but I don't get a response from the php server

What kind of protocal should I use for this?

Comment: What is `response.status_code` ?

Comment: well the output code I get is 200.

Comment: Then you are getting a response from the server. If `response.text` is empty then check your php code.

Comment: cool I got it working. I needed to uses 'response.text' if you wan't you can answer the question so I can confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

To output the result of your post you have to print out `response.text` `print(response.text);`